# Power BI Datasets from REST API and PowerBI Designer

Tags: powerbi

Is it possible to load datasets created by the Power BI REST API as data sources in the Power BI Designer?  Is this functionality planned?  This would be useful for using Power BI Queries to combine data from other sources (e.g. older data in Azure DBs/tables) with the very latest data (e.g. for the current day, hour, etc) that has been loaded via the API.
Also, at the moment it is not possible to perform a selective delete (only Clear All Rows).  Is this planned for the future?
Of course we are still in preview, but it seems some more features like this are needed to support production scenarios.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this is something we're considering but it's more of an idea stage at this point.  Would you submit this request our support site? https://support.powerbi.com/forums/265200-power-bi

We use the support site to track feature requests to we can track requests and keep you updated when features you're interested in come online.

Thanks,
-Lukasz

- http://dev.powerbi.com
- http://blogs.msdn.com/powerbidev

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  For future readers of this question, it is possible to vote for this feature on the Power BI support site (URL in Lukasz answer above).  Then search for the feature "Enable Power BI Datasets from REST API in the Power BI Designer" to vote for it.